# Where can I find data about hyperfine levels of a given atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, hyperfine-structure

The [NIST Atomic Spectra Database](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html) is an excellent resource for finding the energy levels of atoms and the transitions between them, and (together with the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/)) is a good candidate for the number-one useful resource they don't tell you about in undergrad.

Given how useful it is, I was hoping it would also contain data about the hyperfine structure over the periodic table (necessarily broken down by isotope as well as ionization state), but I tried to slice it several ways and no hyperfine structures fell out.

I am looking for a table or web-accessible database where I can plug in an isotope and it will tell me the hyperfine level structure of each electronic state (at least the ground state; if possible also the more important excited electronic states) along with total spins and so on. Given how often BEC people need to go looking for a trappable atom with hyperfine ground-state spin $F=$(some predetermined number), I imagine there's at least some reasonably well-established bit of literature infrastructure to do this, but I can't seem to find it. Where should I look?

Comment: I saw this question on the front page and thought "oh, the NIST database." But the first sentence is asking for more than that. Then I thought, "I bet @EmilioPisanty would know the answer," but got down to the author of the question. I am pretty sure that I *have* gotten some hyperfine information from *somewhere* in NIST's voluminous collection of web-accessible data, but it's been a long time since I've dug through.

Comment: Unfortunately I think no such useful reference exists, but I hope to be proven wrong

Comment: @KFGauss I would hope for such a reference as well, but, alas, I fear that there is as yet no unified place for this information.

Comment: @rob Thanks for the kind words!